# How do I select values based on a specific value in a Table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, select

Using T-SQL, 'List Salespeople who have a commision rate higher than Anne Greens commision rate'.

I cannot for the life of me find anything where I can specify or figure out what anne greens commission rate is in the table. So far for my select statement I have

```
Select EmployeeName From Salespeople Where (Commrate > ???)
```

And I am using this table

```
CREATE TABLE Salespeople (
EmployeeID char(4) PRIMARY KEY,
EmployeeName varchar(30) NOT NULL,
CommRate int,
BaseSalary int,
SupervisorID char(4))
```

How do I find what Anne Greens commission rate is to use it to compare to my other employees?

Comment: `Select EmployeeName From Salespeople Where Commrate > (SELECT MAX(Commrate) FROM SalesPeople WHERE EmployeeName = 'Anne Greens')`

Comment: Thanks! Lecturer isn't really helpful so have to turn to this site :) Works perfectly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT EmployeeName From Salespeople Where Commrate > (SELECT Commrate from Salespeople where EmployeeName = 'Anne Greens')
```